# How to get the second element using jquery

Tags: jquery

Using this jquery code I am trying to change the display from none to block for the 
second ul under Sale which is under Belts (It has a belts-1 href). The below code
should be accessing the second element but its not. What am I doing wrong?

```
$currentCategory = "Belts";
$(".sideCatMenu a:contains('" + currentCategory + "') ul").next(ul).eq(2).css('display', 'block');
```

I am searching this list

```
<li class="active"><a href="/sale/" class="parentSide">Sale</a><ul style="display: block;" class="subcat">
<li><a href="/accessories-3/">Accessories</a><ul style="display: none;">
<li><a href="/bags-1/">Bags</a></li>
<li><a href="/wristbands/">Wristbands</a></li>
<li><a href="/dog-collars/">Dog Collars</a></li>
<li><a href="/wallets/">Wallets</a></li>

</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="/ten-dollar-buckles/">Ten Dollar Buckles</a></li>
<li><a href="/belts-1/">Belts</a><ul style="display: none;">
<li><a href="/28-belts/">28" Belts</a></li>
<li><a href="/30-belts/">30" Belts</a></li>
<li><a href="/32-belts/">32" Belts</a></li>
<li><a href="/34-belts/">34" Belts</a></li>
<li><a href="/36-belts/">36" Belts</a></li>
<li><a href="/38-belts/">38" Belts</a></li>
<li><a href="/40-belts/">40" Belts</a></li>
<li><a href="/42-belts/">42" Belts</a></li>
<li><a href="/44-belts/">44" Belts</a></li>
<li><a href="/46-belts/">46" Belts</a></li>
<li><a href="/48-and-larger-belts/">48" and Larger Belts</a></li>

</ul>
</li>

</ul>
</li>
```

Comment: 1. Which element are you trying to select? 2. You've got `</ul>`s with no corresponding `<ul>`s. Fix your markup.

Comment: @undefined Thanks for your help that ended up getting the first ul "Belts" but the not the second UL which is actually a child of belts. I basically need to get the second ul.

Comment: If you want undefined to be notified of your reply, you should comment on undefined's answer, not your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - Your anchor doesn't have `ul` child so:

```
$(".sideCatMenu a:contains('" + currentCategory + "') ul")
```

Doesn't select any element, it should be:

```
$(".sideCatMenu a:contains('" + currentCategory + "')")
```

2 - You should wrap the `ul` with quotation marks:

```
next('ul')
```

3 - `next` only selects one element, so using `eq` in your code doesn't make sense.

4 - In you code `currentCategory` is `undefined` as you have a variable named `$currentCategory` not `currentCategory`.

Well, let's try this:

```
$(".sideCatMenu a:contains('"+$currentCategory+"')").next('ul').show()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help that ended up getting the first ul "Belts" but the not the second UL which is actually a child of belts. I basically need to get the second ul.

Comment: @Jesse You are welcome, where is the second `ul` in your markup? Note that when a parent element is hidden, it's children will be hidden too.

Comment: Here is a link to the complete div http://tinypaste.net/wcLYJHCb. Line 129 is the div that should be changed from none to block. Right now your code seems to access the ul for line 119.

Comment: @Jesse Okay, try this: `$(".sideCatMenu a:contains('"+$currentCategory+"')").eq(1).next('ul').show()`

Comment: No luck with that either. I put it all in a JSFIDDLE for easier testing and nothing happens with the code you provided http://jsfiddle.net/m8z6c/1/. Any other ideas?

Comment: @Jesse Where do you define the `$cuurentCategory` in your fiddle? also you even haven't loaded jQuery there. http://jsfiddle.net/YSDmJ/

Comment: Thank you again. Using your Fiddle how can I show the sub-categories under the sub-categories of SALE? For example there are more categories under SALE > BELTS, and SALE > ACCCESSORIES but I can't figure how to target them to show.

Comment: @Jesse Sorry, you should ask another question for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead :

```
$(".sideCatMenu a:contains('" + currentCategory + "') ul")
                .nextAll("ul:eq(1)").css('display', 'block');
```

`eq` starts with index 0, so for 2nd element it should be "1".

Answer (score 0):

You can directly interact with any element of the UL array like this:

```
$("ul.subcat li").index(2);
```